# CiviVolunteer 2.0 fails to enable volunteer management for events

Tags: civivolunteer, 4.6.8

I'm running CiviVolunteer 2.0 beta 2 with CiviCRM 4.6.8 on Drupal 7. After installing the extension, I create a test even and attempt to enable volunteer management. Here's the resultant error and stack:

```
Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Not enough data to create volunteer project object.
```

and...

```
#0 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(360): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/org.civicrm.volunteer-4.6-2.0.beta2/CRM/Volunteer/BAO/Project.php(221): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Not enough data to create volunteer project object.")
#2 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/org.civicrm.volunteer-4.6-2.0.beta2/CRM/Volunteer/Form/Volunteer.php(89): CRM_Volunteer_BAO_Project::create((Array:4))
#3 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/org.civicrm.volunteer-4.6-2.0.beta2/CRM/Volunteer/Form/Volunteer.php(285): CRM_Volunteer_Form_Volunteer->saveProject((Array:2))
#4 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(345): CRM_Volunteer_Form_Volunteer->postProcess()
#5 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(166): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#6 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(133): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform(Object(CRM_Volunteer_Form_Volunteer), "upload")
#7 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform(Object(CRM_Volunteer_Form_Volunteer), "upload")
#8 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Volunteer_Form_Volunteer), "upload")
#9 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("upload")
#10 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(115): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#11 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(286): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Volunteer_Form_Volunteer", "Manage Volunteer", NULL)
#12 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#13 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#14 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#15 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("event", "manage", "volunteer")
#16 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:3))
#17 /var/www/drupal/cfsc/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#18 {main}
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer, but I believe the blog post announcing the beta 2 release acknowledged this error. At that stage, the standalone volunteer project functionality was prioritized over the event integration. The bugs introduced in the volunteer/event integration were addressed before the final 2.0 release, and these features are working together nicely now.